# rails内部からgem内のファイルを参照する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

jpstockというgemの中に
lib/jpstock/edinet.csv
というファイルがあるのですが、このファイルをrails内部から参照する方法を教えて欲しいです。
rails内からcsvファイルを開きたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[find_files](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Gem/find_files/class)
を使うのはいかがでしょうか？

```
[23] pry(main)> Gem.find_files("jquery-rails.rb")
=> ["/***/vendor/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/lib/jquery-rails.rb"]
```